# exit value regex bash issue

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have to match only number with minus sign for example `-20` , `-2000` , `-9000` ... and The script has to exit with exit value equal to absolute value of number.
for example if the input is `-20` the script exits with `20`. 
For this reason I do this:

```
numpat='^-([0-9]+)$'

read stringa

if [[ $stringa =~ $numpat ]]
then

    value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$value"
    exit $value
fi
```

My problem is when I execute this script because if for example I insert `-20` when it do `echo "$value"` it prints `"20"`, but when the execution ends and I do on terminal `echo $?` (for see exit value) it prints `236` and I don't understand why

Comment: Checked locally and it works fine in bash

Comment: Hi @gino-gino, same as fedorqui. Have you try to put your script into a file and run it?

Comment: @gino-gino : Funny , I ran your script on my mac and the `if` part is killing the session literally

Comment: @AndyK you should store it into a script and run it there. Otherwise, the `exit` command quits from your current session.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui , I understand now. Yes when running from a script, there are no issues.

Comment: yes I insert it into file test.sh and I execute it by ./test.sh

Comment: now I don't understand why exit value is wrong

Comment: Add `set -vx` to the top of the script and show the output from running the script?

Answer (score 2):

When I run this code, I get an exit value of 20. Your main problem is that you aren't capturing the minus sign with your regular expression; `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` is just `20`, not `-20`. As written, `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` would be `-20`.

Your second problem is expecting `exit` to return a signed value; it only works with unsigned values between 0 and 255. `-20` is being treated as the unsigned value 236. Instead of using `exit`, you should simply write the value to standard output, and capture it when you run the script:

```
# Put the - inside the parentheses to capture it
numpat='^(-[0-9]+)$'

read stringa

if [[ $stringa =~ $numpat ]]
then

    value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$value"
fi
```

Then use something like

```
$ value=$(bash myScript)
-20
$ echo "The value is $value"
The value is -20
```

Comment: Regarding the first problem you mention: OP is already aware of it and capturing the absolute value of the number. At least this is what I understand from the question.

Comment: I have to return only the absolute value and not the sign. My problem isn't how extract only absolute value from input , but my problem is that when the script ends and I do echo $? , I don't get the absolute value but another number. For example if I insert -20 as input , the script ends with 236 exit value, but where does it came from?